# My donut project can no longer render, computer freezes. Cannot fix!

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I was following blender gurus tutorials and got to the part where I textured the cake area of the donut and when I try to render it, nothing shows up and it freezes my computer and I have to turn my computer off and on again.

I have no idea what settings I should lower in order for it to render better and I've already tried the decimation option, doesn't seem to work. The only other thing I can think May be the issue is the graphics card I have right now. I have a GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER. I am not extremely tech savvy, just a well-seasoned artist trying to understand 3D better.

[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/8LbOxlGW

Comment: theres the file

Answer (score 3):

go to your modifiers and delete the subdivision surface modifiers. I even don't know why you had 3 of them...

[image]

Comment: ..... Huh.... You know, I'll be completely honest with you. I don't know why I did either, haha!  Cannot thank you enough!

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please check my answer as correct?